Chatbot in Python: Responses not matching tags correctly
I'm a high school junior working on a chatbot project using Python 3.10 in Visual Studio in my own virtual environment that supports TensorFlow. I'm building it without APIs. The bot recognizes the tags from the user input successfully but often fails to return the correct responses. Instead, it selects any random response from the responses brace.
What I'm trying to do:

Store Chatbot data(tags, patterns, responses) in a JSON file.
Match user input to tag and return a response from the corresponding list.
I used random to shuffle the greetings and farewells, later deleted to see if the code works better without the random module.

The problem I'm encountering:

The bot recognizes tags correctly but selects inconsistent responses.

I asked "who discovered gravity", and it responded with "Da Vinci painted the Mona Lisa".


Relevant code:
Function for selecting responses and leading functions:
def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    """Tokenize and lemmatize the input sentence."""
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words

def bag_of_words(sentence):
    """Convert a sentence into a bag-of-words representation."""
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    bag = [0] * len(words)
    for w in sentence_words:
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word == w:
                bag[i] = 1
    return np.array(bag)

def predict_class(sentence):
    """Predict the intent class for a given sentence."""
    bow = bag_of_words(sentence)
    res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
    ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.8
    results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > ERROR_THRESHOLD]
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    if not results:
        return []

    return [{'intent': classes[r[0]], 'probability': str(r[1])} for r in results]

def get_response(intents_list):
    """Generate a response based on predicted intents."""
    if not intents_list:
        return "I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. Could you rephrase?"

    tag = intents_list[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for intent in list_of_intents:
        if intent['tag'] == tag:
            return intent['responses']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        user_input = input("You: ")
        intents = predict_class(user_input)
        response = get_response(intents)
        print(f"Bot: {response}")


Sample JSON file:
{
  "tag": "general_knowledge",
  "patterns": [
    "who invented the lightbulb",
    "what is the capital of France",
    "who painted the Mona Lisa",
    "when was the Declaration of Independence signed",
    "what is the square root of 144",
    "who discovered gravity",
    "what is the largest planet in our solar system"
  ],
  "responses": [
    "The lightbulb was invented by Thomas Edison.",
    "The capital of France is Paris.",
    "The Mona Lisa was painted by Leonardo da Vinci.",
    "The Declaration of Independence was signed on July 4, 1776.",
    "The square root of 144 is 12.",
    "Gravity was discovered by Sir Isaac Newton.",
    "The largest planet in our solar system is Jupiter."
  ]
}


What I've tried:

Verified the JSON file.
Checked the response matching logic.
Tried printing debug statements to confirm the correct tag is being passed.
Tried deleting the random module.

The big question:
How can the bot respond according to the question asked instead of selecting random responses from the tag's list?
I'm grateful for any insights that could help me resolve this issue. I’ve invested much time in this school project; your assistance would mean a lot!

Is the sample json part of intents_json?

Welcome to [so]! Please consider going through the [tour]. Now, you have provided enough information which explains the issue you are facing but there is not enough code where someone can help you. For eg: you have mentioned random module multiple times but there is no code which shows how you are using it. Please add more relevant code and provide a [mre].

yes the sample json is part of intents_json
